# About reduce() method importing in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, tuples, mapping, reduce

Importing

```
    import reduce from functools
```

Creating a list of strings: stark

```
    stark = ['robb', 'sansa', 'arya', 'brandon', 'rickon']
```

Using reduce() to apply a lambda function over stark: result

```
    result = reduce(lambda item1 , item2 : item1 + item2 ,stark)
```

Print the result

```
    print(result)
```

In this simple code I am getting a syntax error on line 2- import reduce from functools
further I also tried out importing functools for reduce()
but it didn't work out.

Comment: `from functools import reduce`

Comment: Well I tried this and it has worked out..thanks..can you explain the problem with my syntax and the background system processing change related to the import statement.Thanks in advance/..

Comment: The syntax is `from module import class/function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in the question comments, to import a `class/function` from a `module`, the syntax is:

```
from module import class/function
```

So in your case, you should be using:

```
from functools import reduce
```

Happy Coding! :)